# Why doesn't Epson driver show up in Software Update as Epson claims it will?

Tags: macos, software-update, printing, driver

I'm following [Epson's guide for installing OS X 10.9 Epson drivers](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=130786&BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_M_X9) for Workforce 610, which says to use OS X Software Update to install. Unfortunately, nothing under "Updates" mentions Epson.

I've tried connecting to printer with both USB and Wireless network, and neither work.

The printer already works with an existing Mac on the network.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the Software Update page was simply cached, and pushing `Cmd+R` on the keyboard forced it to recheck for updates.